# Перевернуть стек на основе массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, стек

Написать программу, которая реализует структуру данных "стек« (`LIFO` структура с методами `pop ()` и `push (value))` на основе массива (используя list в python) и добавляет к ней метод `reverse`, который заменяет порядок элементов стека на противоположный.
Пример входных данных:

```
14

push 10.0

push 11.0

push 12.0

push 13.0

reverse 

push 14.0

push 15.0

reverse

pop

push 16.0

reverse

pop

push 17.0

reverse
```

Результат:

```
16.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 14.0 17.0
```

Я все никак не могу понять как это сделать?

Comment: создать стек, используя список, и описать в нем методы, которые вы описали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Stack()
    _list = []

    def append(self, elema):
        self._list.append(elem)

    def pop(self):
        return self._list.pop()

    def reverse(self):
        return self._list.reverse()
```

Comment: я заметил вы часто помогаете незаслужившим)

Comment: Зато репу зарабатываю ) Хотя не всегда удачно , например про скобки было что-то ...

Comment: с кем не бывает)

Comment: Я кстати тот ответ обозначил как общий , чтоб было справедливо.